# How do I inject Maven into my docker image?

Tags: docker, maven

I have a docker image that has to **programmatically** compile code as part of it's runtime algorithm.
It uses the following code:

```
 if (!Files.exists(rootPath)) {
            throw new BoilerplateBuildException(String.format("The directory to compile \"%s\" does not exist.", rootPath == null ? "N/A" : rootPath.toString()));
        }

        Path pomPath = Paths.get(rootPath.toString(), "pom.xml");
        if (!Files.exists(pomPath)) {
            throw new BoilerplateBuildException(String.format("The MAVEN pom file \"%s\" does not exist.", pomPath.toString()));
        }

        InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
        request.setPomFile( new File( pomPath.toString() ) );
        request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("compile"));
        request.setBaseDirectory(new File(rootPath.toString()));

        Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
        try {
            invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("MAVEN_HOME")));

            InvocationResult result = invoker.execute( request );

            if(result != null && result.getExitCode() != 0){
                throw new BoilerplateBuildException(String.format("Failed to build with maven in path \"%s\" (Check the inner exception for further details).", pomPath.toString()), result.getExecutionException());
            }
        } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to build with maven for \"%s\"", pomPath.toString()), e);
        }
```

Using the following artifact

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

But this is merely a client. Not Maven itself.
Of course that on the local development machine it works since I have Maven installed on it. **But when my code is running as a docker container it's a whole other story**.
So my question is - Can I "inject" Maven into my docker image (With it's environment variables of course like `MAVEN_HOME`) so it will be available to my code?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `maven` image in which java is already installed. Probably, you can choose the tag which `maven` and `java` version you want to use.

> Ref:- https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Using, the maven base image, you can build your image from `Dockerfile`.

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

and inside the container, you will be able to run `maven` or `java` commands